# Kate - cannot open remote (SFTP) file

Tags: remote, sftp, kate, krusader

I need to open remote files with Kate. I am connected to remote server through SFTP in Krusader. When I open remote file with Kate, I got this error message:

`Could not start process Unable to create io-slave:
klauncher said: Unknown protocol 'sftp'.
.`

I was googling this error, but haven't found any solution :(

Comment: `sshfs` is an easy alternative, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39475747/open-file-from-remote-host-with-kate   also, for me it works to type `kate sftp://username@server/path/on/server` on the command line while it does not work to open that path from the Open File dialog within Kate

Answer (score 2):

I had to install kio-extras to get SFTP capability in Kate.

Comment: I assume your running KDE, it might be helpful to mention that in your answer.

Comment: Kate is part of KDE. klauncher is part of KDE. kio is part of KDE. I'm actually running XFCE, but to use Kate, I have to have proper KDE libraries installed.

Comment: So [edit]ing that information into your answer might be useful to those who aren't as knowledgeable as yourself wouldn't it?

Comment: No. It wouldn't. The question isn't "How can I make Kate work in KDE?" The question is "How can I make Kate work?" Kate is part of KDE, but you don't have to run KDE to make Kate work. You can use Kate in Gnome if you like. I run it in XFCE. The solution to the problem is to install the dependency. For me, the dependency is a package named kio-extras - and I'm still not running KDE. I'm still running XFCE.

Comment: Well, I think it's valuable information so I've upvoted your comment. I think we can agree to disagree on that point.